# UNIX scripting - Changing a field of one file, based on matching a condition from a field in a second file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have two (huge ~100 GB) files, with text of multiple fields distinguished by their fixed position in the line (not delimited.)

When the text at a specific position (say, positions 16-20) in File1 contains a numerical value less than some value of my choosing (for example, less than -5), I wish to change a corresponding field (also given at a fixed position on the line) in the second file to some pre-set value (say 10).  By corresponding, I mean they are at the same line-number (in the example case below - both are at line 3 in their respective files)

E.g.File1:

> ABC (11 spaces) 5.78 3.65 9.22 (more important stuff)
>
> EFG (11 spaces) 4.78 9.65 9.99 (more important stuff)
>
> HIJ (11 spaces)**-5.78** 9.99 9.99 (more important stuff)

File 2 (before):

> LMN (11 spaces)31.21 2.14 1.27 (more important stuff)
>
> OPQ (11 spaces) 4.78 9.99 9.99 (more important stuff)
>
> RST (11 spaces) **3.29** 9.99 9.99 (more important stuff)

File 2 (after):

> LMN (11 spaces)31.21 2.14 1.27 (more important stuff)
>
> OPQ (11 spaces) 4.78 9.99 9.99 (more important stuff)
>
> RST (11 spaces)**10.00** 9.99 9.99 (more important stuff)

This seems like it should be a very simple task for some Unix guru using the scripting utilities, but I am not familiar enough with these tools to string them together and solve the task.  I have only been able to accomplish parts of it, such as selecting out the fields based on position using "cut".  For example, I have done this in the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# PURPOSE: Process a file line by line with PIPED while-read loop.
FILENAME=$1
count=0
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
xcoor=$(echo "$LINE" | cut -c 16-20)
let count++
if [ "$xcoor" -lt -4 ] 
then
echo "$count"
#I have identified the lines I want in the first file.  
#Now I need to modify the second file
fi
done
```

Part of my issue is simply the fact that I'm dealing with 2 files at once.
The biggest issue is the aforementioned massive size of the files - which is why I think it is important to do it on a line-by-line basis - avoiding reading the entire file into memory - or unnecessary writing of temporary files.

Any help is much appreciated, and if you would be so kind as to give a brief description of what the components of the commands do, that would be very helpful, because I would like to understand what the commands do, so that I can modify them as needed (I am a beginner of Unix scripting.)

Thanks!

Comment: better [edit] your question giving a proper format and also showing what you tried so far

Comment: What do you mean by proper format?  The example files are of the format needed.

Comment: For the 2-file issue, see `paste`. It will join together corresponding lines from the two files which you can then process as if it were a single file (in a streaming fashion, that is, without having to create a temp file).

Comment: Thanks @jas, that is helpful.  I will try it.  However, I also need to modify the second file.  Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Yes, pipe the output of paste into awk (e.g.). If the portion of the line from File1 matches your criteria, output the (modified) portion of the line from File2.

Comment: Thanks again, @jas, but won't this create another copy of the file (remember, these files are big, so I want to avoid writing new files)?  Or can I also overwrite the same file while reading it line-by-line?

Comment: It will create another copy of the (second) file. As far as I know it's generally quite difficult to surgically modify a file without either creating a new one and moving it back to the original name (streaming style, like `sed -i` does for you), or by having it all in memory and then deleting and rewriting the entire file with the new contents (as an editor like vi or emacs would do). That said, I'm no expert so maybe some other commenters can say more about that (and have better news for you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86765/discussion-between-user3133172-and-jas).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this with `gawk`

```
gawk '
  BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="15 5 5"}      # widths of the fields - you will need to set this for your files
  FNR==NR{if($2<-5)r[NR]++;next}   # this processing only applies to file1
  FNR in r{$2="10.00"}             # this processing only applies to file2
  1' file1 file2                   # the '1' prints the record

LMN           31.21 2.14 1.27
OPQ            4.78 9.99 9.99
RST            10.00 9.99
```

So, we read both files using `gawk`'s fixed width fields. When reading the first one, note all records that need fixing in the array `r[]`. When reading the second, fix any records that need it, then print.

The only thing held in memory is the list of all the record numbers that need fixing.

My input files may differ from yours. Direct the output to a new file if you want to, with

```
gawk '...' file1 file2 > newFile
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, thank you (also thanks for the descriptions - very helpful!)  The only problem is, it seems to overwrite the last part of the last line, and add an extra line with a "10":

LMN (11 spaces)31.21 2.14 1.27 (more important stuff)

OPQ (11 spaces) 4.78 9.99 9.99 (more important stuff)

RST (11 spaces) 10  9.99

 10

Comment: You probably need to check your fieldwidths match your data, and also that when you put `10` in field 2, you actually put `10.00` to match the length of the removed part, if it is 5 characters, or `10.000` if it is 6 characters for example.

Comment: it's close - i was considering just accepting it, but for some reason, it overwrites some of the characters, or adds extra space.  I tried changing the lengths of the fields, but i can't get it to work.  you can even see in your example output there is some issue with the alignment and the last field being missing.  i fixed the extra line by adding a condition to test for a zero length field: ...FNR==NR{if($2<-90&&$2!="")...